# How to vertically center div in floated div?

Tags: css

I'm trying to do something that doesn't seem to have been asked.  I have a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kahanu/zo7yj3s0/4/

I have two floated divs side-by-side, the left div has content that creates height of the parent div.  The right div will simply have buttons that need to be vertically centered in whatever height the left div creates.  So there are no known dimensions, either height or width.

Here's what I have:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="line">
        <div class="left">
            <p>This is some content to create some height to the div.  </p>
            <p>This is some content to create some height to the div.  </p>
            <p>This is some content to create some height to the div.  </p>
            <p>This is some content to create some height to the div.  </p>
            <p>This is some content to create some height to the div.  </p>
            <p>This is some content to create some height to the div.  </p>
            <p>This is some content to create some height to the div.  </p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <button>Center me vertically</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.parent {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    display: table;
}

.line {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: blue;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I feel like I'm close, I'm just missing an important concept.

So how can I vertically center the button in the right-hand div?

Comment: Ok, this is a tough one.  You both have presented working examples, but created them in two different ways.  Is one more reliable or better than the other?  More mobile friendly also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Vertical align only applies to inline or inline-block elements. It affects the
>   alignment of the element itself, not its contents (except when applied
>   to table cells) When it’s applied to a table cell, the alignment
>   affects the cell contents, not the cell itself

Read more on this here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/

What you can apply this CSS to your button.

```
button{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

If you're into using mixins you can simply write a vertical alignment rule and reuse throughout your project.

Mixin:

```
@mixin vertical-align($position: relative) {
  position: $position;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
```

}

CSS:

```
button {
  @include vertical-align();
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/gaBzNm)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating the divs you could set their display to table-cell instead:

```
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zo7yj3s0/5/)**